# Ember components crashes on production

Tags: javascript, ember.js, digital-ocean

I'm having issues with my ember app when i build it on production, using `ember serve` all components work beautifully, but when I deploy it in my Digital Ocean droplet with Ubuntu 16.04 the app crashes with one component.

Here you had the code of the component that crashes:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import pagedArray from 'ember-cli-pagination/computed/paged-array';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.send('fillQuestions');
  },
  didDestroyElement(){
    this.send('reset');
  },
  last: false,
  toggleModal: false,
  aciertos: 0,
  errores: 0,
  contenido: Ember.computed('questions', function () {
    let i = 0,
        content = [],
        contenido = [];
    for (i; i < this.get('questions.length'); i++) {
      content.push(this.get('questions.' + i + '.id_question_group.questions'));
    }

    contenido = [].concat.apply([], content);
    return contenido;
  }),
  count: 0,
  page: 1,
  perPage: 1,
  pagedContent: pagedArray('contenido', {
    pageBinding: "page",
    perPageBinding: "perPage"
  }),
  totalPagesBinding: "pagedContent.totalPages", 
  progressValue: 0,
  color: Ember.computed('count', function () {
    return new Ember.String.htmlSafe("width: " + this.get('progressValue') + "%;");
  }),
  actions: {
    ...(all my actions)
  }
});
```

Inside my view I had this:

```
{{#if exam.show_progressbar}}
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={{progressValue}} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style={{color}}>
    <span>{{progressValue}}%</span>
</div>
{{/if}}
{{#if exam.show_time}}
  {{countdown-timer autoStart='false' startTime=exam.duration action='saveresponse'}}
{{/if}}
{{#each pagedContent as |result index|}}
<div class="text-center">
  <p>{{result.questionID.description}}</p>
  <br/><br/>
</div>
<form {{action 'saveresponse' on="submit"}}>
  {{radio-group group=result.questionID.temp elements=result.questionID.rows action="updateValues" nombre=result.questionID.description}}
  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column text-left">
      <button type="button" {{action 'showAlert'}} class="btn btn-primary">
        Cancelar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{#if last}}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-right">
      <div class="column text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Guardar examen
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/if}}
</form>
{{/each}}
<div class="pager">
   {{page-numbers content=pagedContent currentPage=page action='checkLast'}}
</div>
```

The error its in the next components: `{{countdown-timer}}` and `{{radio-group}}`

The countdown-timer is a component based on [ember-cli-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-timer) which counts from a set time to 0 and the radio-group component only had inside a radio-button helper.

Any ideas of why in production is not working and locally it's working?

**UPDATE 03-23-2017**

Using the chrome developer tools I've got this error, maybe this will explain a little more my problem.

`Property set failed: You passed an empty path`

**UPDATE 04-24-2017**

I just had found the exact error in the component, it's the next action:

```
actions: {
    ...
    fillQuestions(){
        let questions = this.get('contenido'); //Filled with exam questions
        for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
            if(questions[i].questionID !== null && questions[i].questionID !== undefined){
                console.log(questions[i].questionID.description); //consoles the description of the question
                this.set(questions[i].questionID.description, ''); //here it's the problem.
            }
        }
     }
     ...
  }
```

The line with `this.set()` its making the problem, and it's because `questions[i].questionID.description` it's the `empty path` it's there a way to create new properties in the component with an action of the same?

Comment: Is your exam.duration set when it is passed into your countdown timer? You can add a `{{log exam.duration}}` to check ...

Comment: @acorncom The log show that the `{{exam.duration}}` it's not empty, I will try to lookup all the variables in the template maybe it's one of them.

Comment: You have a CP that depends on itself which loops suspicious: `contenido: Ember.computed('contenido'`

Comment: @locks I forgot to update that, I've already correct that, the ```Ember.computed``` it's looking to 'questions' which is a property passed from the route.

Comment: if you want to define description property to empty then Instead of `this.set(questions[i].questionID.description, '')`, you can try `Ember.set(questions[i].questionID, 'description', '')`.  In your case `this.set` will create new property in component and that's not required here as you are not using it as properties rather than as an array

Comment: @kumkanillam Actually I want to define a property named like the description of the question and set it empty at first, and then when an answer is given update the value of that exact property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error, the error was displayed when the component tried to set the new property.

The real problem was:
when I attempted to save the property of the question some questions got "." and it seems to be that `Ember.computed` does not allow to use them for a property, so when I tried `this.set('some.question.with.dots', '')` the error was triggered and display the `Property set failed`.

The solution was simple, I only had to use `.replace()` function of javascript to replace all the dots in the string.

The final code is next:

```
actions: {
    ...
    fillQuestions(){
        let questions = this.get('contenido'); //Filled with exam questions
        for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
            if(questions[i].questionID !== null && questions[i].questionID !== undefined){
                let desc = questions[i].questionID.description.replace(/\./g,'');
                this.set(desc, ''); //the problem has gone
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Thank to all of the people that support me with they points of view.